# Why does my java project still work even though its missing some packages?

Tags: java, gradle

I am working on a `Dubbo` project and when I digging a little deep into its source code. I found these code in `Dubbo`'s source code:

[image]

I think this shows that my project missing the `org.jboss.*`package
**(IDEA has mark these packages in red)**

But somehow this project still working, doesn't it supposed to not working due to it has some package missing?

By the way my project is organized by `gradle` and the `build.gradle` is like this:

```
dependencies 
{
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
        compile group: 'org.apache.dubbo', name: 'dubbo-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.7.8'
        compile group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', name: 'zookeeper', version: '3.6.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.curator', name: 'curator-framework', version: '5.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Could be that your ide is out of sync. I've found that occasionally I have to refresh IntelliJ for it to accurately reflect the dependencies.

Comment: Sometimes IntelliJ won't update dependency indices until you attempt a build for the first time

Comment: @Rogue so is there someway to read the correct source-code?

Comment: My suggestion was to attempt building it regardless of the errors, and if the dependency is valid then your build system will use it, and IntelliJ I believe will pick up on the reference

Comment: @Rogue I‘ve try the following steps: **1.** click run button in IDEA     **2.** select `NettyServer` class.  **3.** right click, go to its declaration.    But it still mark the `org.jboss.*` packages in red.

Answer (score 1):

If this wouldn't be some library's de-compiled byte-code but your application's source code, this would rather be an issue. And it's not missing anything, but Gradle will pull in [`org.jboss.netty`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty) on demand, which will then pull in another 8 libraries, which may evetually even pull in further libraries.

Comment: sorry I don't quite get your point. doesn't all transitive dependency downloaded by `gradle` is shown in IDEA's `External Libraries`? If so, how `gradle` > will put org.jboss.netty on demand?

Comment: All of netty's dependencies are optional, is what it states there: https://netty.io ... if you want to have it listed as external library, just include it as a project dependency. They renamed the package to `io.netty:netty-all`... but actually: you don't need it and you don't have to worry about it. If it builds, it is probably save to assume that everything is there. If you'd build [`org.apache.dubbo`](https://github.com/apache/dubbo) from source, then it has to be reference by that module. What you are looking at there is no source code, which may be the cause of confusion.

Comment: Actually this is what puzzled me: I know they rename it to `io.netty : netty-all`, but my IDEA still shows `org.jboss.netty.*`, I just wonder why...but  now I think this is just some features of the IDE which somehow shows the old source code

Comment: This is simply because that dubbo library is built against the old one library's namespace... which likely could be refactored, in order to build against the new one's namespace (if that doesn't break too much).

Comment: Thx a lot for your reply, but I actually not asking about how dubbo project changes...I just wonder why even if I put the newest dubbo version in `build.gradle`, my IDE still show the old source-code when I execute·right-click, go to declaration·...I know they rename `jboss` to `io.netty` for some reason..